# What is an effective way to capture a signature from a user?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project where it would be desirable to capture a signature from the user once they have read over our policy documents.  The way that I have went about it is to use the GestureOverlayView class.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.jtryon.signaturecap.app;

import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void saveSig(View view) {
        try {
            GestureOverlayView gestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.signaturePad);
            gestureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getDrawingCache());
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "signature.png");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            //compress to specified format (PNG), quality - which is ignored for PNG, and out stream
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Gestures", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.jtryon.signaturecap.app.MainActivity">

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
        android:fadeEnabled="false"
        android:gestureColor="#000000"
        android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="saveSig"
        android:text="@string/send" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I can sign my name on the pad even though it is difficult because when the hand is lifted off the pad, the signature in the box gets erased.  The signature is saved to a file called "signature.png", but when I search for the file on my system, it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Do you wish to simply get a signature as a image or do you also want to authenticate the user by his signature? The later can be done using JavaCv(OpenCv Wrapper). For simply getting the signature, you can create a custom view. Make a class to extend the View class, override onTouchEvent, then here you can use Path.lineTo(X,Y).

Answer (score 0):

you may try the Canvas for the signature.
using for it you could overcome your problem.